# Dropdown menu not working on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have searched high and low and tried many different options from here, but i need a point in the right direction now :)

On this site:

http://www.michael-smith-engineers.co.uk

On the main nav, (in mobile view) if you click on Pumps, there should be further dropdown options, but i can not get this working. Any ideas would be appreciated.

I have tried adding the following script, without any luck...

```
<script>
// see whether device supports touch events (a bit simplistic, but...)
var hasTouch = ("ontouchstart" in window);
var iOS5 = /iPad|iPod|iPhone/.test(navigator.platform) && "matchMedia" in window;

// hook touch events for drop-down menus
// NB: if has touch events, then has standards event handling too
// but we don't want to run this code on iOS5+
if (hasTouch && document.querySelectorAll && !iOS5) {
    var i, len, element,
        dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll("#nav-site li.children > a");

    function menuTouch(event) {
        // toggle flag for preventing click for this link
        var i, len, noclick = !(this.dataNoclick);

        // reset flag on all links
        for (i = 0, len = dropdowns.length; i < len; ++i) {
            dropdowns[i].dataNoclick = false;
        }

        // set new flag value and focus on dropdown menu
        this.dataNoclick = noclick;
        this.focus();
    }

    function menuClick(event) {
        // if click isn't wanted, prevent it
        if (this.dataNoclick) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }

    for (i = 0, len = dropdowns.length; i < len; ++i) {
        element = dropdowns[i];
        element.dataNoclick = false;
        element.addEventListener("touchstart", menuTouch, false);
        element.addEventListener("click", menuClick, false);
    }
}
</script>
```

This script above is ridiculous for what i was trying so, tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function is_touch_device() {

     return (('ontouchstart' in window) || (navigator.MaxTouchPoints > 0) || (navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0));
  }

  if(is_touch_device()) {

    jQuery('.toggle-menu').on('click', function(){

      jQuery(this).toggleClass('activate');

      jQuery(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
      return false;
    });
  } 
</script>

</head>
```

Still no luck tho?!!!!

Comment: Where is the script that gets triggered when Pumps get clicked? and why it's so complicated for a drop down menu.

Comment: Im not sure to be honest, the site is really old and outdated. Using Protoype js to be even more of a headache

Comment: Can anybody help with this, or suggest anything??